# Dock a window as a toolbar

Tags: c#, windows-7

I'd like to create an app that I can dock to my screen such that when other windows are maximized they neither obscure my app, nor are they hidden behind my app.  "Always on top" is not good enough since other windows can still hide behind it.  It should effectively reduce the available size of my monitor and behave like a toolbar.  Full screen apps *should* obscure my "toolbar".

So, eg, if I dock my app to the right side of my 1920 x 1080 monitor and size it to be 200px wide, the largest window I can have open on that monitor would be 1720 x 1080 (or shorter if it is the main monitor with the Windows task bar).

I remember doing this in Windows XP with just an HTML file and some ActiveX controls.  XP had some shortcut to use that file as a "toolbar".  I can't remember exactly how I did it now.

I haven't seen anything exactly like this on Windows 7.  If the HTML hack is still possible (I believe it isn't) that would be ok, but I'd rather create a native, compiled application.  Is it possible?

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx?df=100&forumid=3788&exp=0&select=862248)?

Comment: Read your question again. Windows 7 (at least as I understand it) only allows a single task bar/place to host "toolbars". In fact it basically removed the ability you had in XP. If you're open to implementing it as a mock toolbar then you should take a look at the source to the [Dual Monitor Task Bar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/) which presents a "fake" task bar which is considered when sizing windows and a dual monitor. Not exactly the same as your situation but may still apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [an article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3) which seems to provide a sample for what you're looking for. The project is to create a desktop-toolbar which remains docked beside other windows on the screen, even if they're maximized.

> *During this article we will develop a class named ApplicationDesktopToolbar. This class inherits
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form. So when we want to make our application to
>   behave like an appbar all we need to do is inherit from
>   ApplicationDesktopToolbar instead of System.Windows.Forms.Form.*

Original article author: [Arik Poznanski](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=172641)

Comment: Sadly, that article is 9 years old. I'm looking for something that will work on Windows 7.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do... When I tried this on my Win7 x64 machine it seemed to work as advertised. The app starts up docked to an edge of the screen (or to the W7 taskbar) and all maximized windows are realigned to fit into the space left by the app...

Comment: Awesome!  Yes, this does appear to work!  Pardon my jumping to conclusions.  I just looked at the date on the article and figured nothing written 9 years ago on .Net 1.0 for Windows XP could possibly still be relevant today on Windows 7.

Comment: That's the beauty of the CLR -- it mostly works the same on all versions of Windows that support it (and in most cases on non-Windows systems thanks to Mono. :) )